# Getting "null" as message from Exception during input mismatch error

Tags: java, exception

I'm doing some basic exception handling in Java. I ask the user for a number and I catch the input mismatch error thrown when the user gives a different kind of input, for example when he/she types in a string or chars instead of a number.

My problem/question is why the message comes back as "null" when I catch an Exception or an IOException.  Granted the type of the exception is very explanatory, but I though any exception would give a more meaningful message.  Is giving "null" as the message common or at least not unique to input mismatch errors?

Here's the code from my main method

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
int y;

try
{   
    System.out.println("Input a number:");
    y = kb.nextInt();
}
catch(Exception e) //also tried IOException, but still got "null" as message
{
    System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    System.out.println("Type of exception: " + e.toString());
}
```

Comment: What is the output you are getting? I mean are u seeing "Error:" and "Type of exception:" in your output

Comment: @Ramesh like this `Error: null
Type of exception: java.util.InputMismatchException
`

Answer (score 1):

Always use the JavaDoc when you need to know what Java classes do.

The JavaDoc says that Scanner.nextInt() can throw these exceptions:

```
InputMismatchException - if the next token does not match the Integer regular expression, or is out of range
NoSuchElementException - if input is exhausted
IllegalStateException - if this scanner is closed
```

If you look at the JavaDoc for those three exceptions, you'll see that none of them are subclasses of `IOException`. Their most specific common ancestor is `RuntimeException`.

Now look at `InputMismatchException`. The JavaDoc shows that it has two constructors - one with a message, and one with nothing. The latter one:

> Constructs an InputMismatchException with null as its error message string.

So you can't guarantee that InputMismatchException.getMessage() won't return null. And in this case you've discovered, that's what it does.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go through the source code to find this. `Scanner#nextInt()` calls `Scanner#nextInt(int)` which calls `Scanner#next(Pattern)` which will throw a `InputMismatchException` without a `message` if it can't find a token in the stream which matches the provided integer `Pattern`.

That exact execution flow will throw an `InputMismatchException` will a `null` `message`. There are other flows which will throw an `InputMismatchException` with an actual `message`.